# Convert XMLDocument to XDocument ,getting names spaces Modifing from xsi to p1

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

i create an XMLDocument:

`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlDeclaration declaire = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
   // -----------------------create root-----------------------------  
                XmlElement rootnode = doc.CreateElement( "BMECAT");
                doc.InsertBefore(declaire, doc.DocumentElement);


                doc.AppendChild(rootnode);




                //Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                //get attribute for BmeCat
                rootnode.SetAttribute("version", "2005");

                XmlAttribute atr = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

                atr.Value = "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3";
                rootnode.SetAttributeNode(atr);
                rootnode.Attributes.Append(atr);`
```

then i convert it to XDocument using the function below but i get a NameSpace changed like this

```
XDocument ToXDocument(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
    {
        nodeReader.MoveToContent();
        return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
    }
}
```

`
below the xml and the XDocument

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BMECAT version="2005" p1:schemaLocation="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BMECAT version="2005" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

Comment: It's always better if you write down the actual xml text instead of posting an image, so that we can see it more clearly and even perform tests with the sample if necessary.

Comment: I usually use : XDocument.Parse(xmlDocument.ToString())

Comment: actually my function is givin the the result expected,but i don't understand why the xsi in my XML is remplaced by p1 in the XDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly add the xsi namespace declaration manually at the beginning of your element.

Nodes are processed in document order and the namespace declaration appears later after it is first used. It doesn't know to use `xsi` for the prefix until it's too late.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
var root = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("BMECAT"));
var xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", xsi); //set the namespace now
root.SetAttribute("schemaLocation", xsi, "http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3");
root.SetAttribute("version", "2005");
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff Mercado ,this is exactly what i want.